# remove duplicate values from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Below is the result and I want to remove duplicate from the array

I tried using this code: `$login_data1['items'] = array_values(array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $login_data1['items']))));`

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "tags": [
                {
                    "name": "Microsoft"
                }
            ],
            "type": "manual",
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "tags": [
                {
                    "name": "Snow Leopard"
                }
            ],
            "type": "faq"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "tags": [
                {
                    "name": "Microsoft"
                }
            ],
           "type": "manual"
        }
    ],
}
```

I tried using `$login_data1['items'] = array_unique($login_data1['items'] ,SORT_REGULAR);` but this adds serial numbers at the each json response

Comment: `$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input)));` try this by putting your variables

Comment: can you show your array format after unserialize it?

Comment: You can try `array_unique($input,SORT_REGULAR)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this.

```
$login_data1['items'] =array_values(array_unique($login_data1['items'] ,SORT_REGULAR));
```

Try array_value and array_unique together and serial number will be removed!

Answer (score 2):

Try as using `array_unique`

```
$json = '{
"items": [
    {
        "id": "2",
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "Microsoft"
            }
        ],
        "type": "manual"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "Snow Leopard"
            }
        ],
        "type": "faq"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "Microsoft"
            }
        ],
       "type": "manual"
    }
]
}';

foreach(json_decode($json, true) as $key => $value){
    $input = array_unique($value,SORT_REGULAR);
}
```

If its an array then simply use

```
array_unique($login_data['items'],SORT_REGULAR);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://eval.in/391860)

Comment: when I try 
$json = $login_data1['items'];
and your code, I am getting "Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

Comment: What is `$login_data1['items']` is it an array or string

Answer (score 0):

array_unique works perfectly if you pass a multidimensional array.

```
$login_data1['items'] = array_unique($login_data1['items'], SORT_REGULAR);
```

It doesn't work with your json because it's an array of object. Infact:

```
  $array = json_decode($json);
  var_dump($array);
```

returns:

```
    object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["items"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["tags"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
          ["name"]=>
          string(9) "Microsoft"
        }
      }
      ["type"]=>
      string(6) "manual"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#4 (3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["tags"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#5 (1) {
          ["name"]=>
          string(12) "Snow Leopard"
        }
      }
      ["type"]=>
      string(3) "faq"
    }
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass)#6 (3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["tags"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#7 (1) {
          ["name"]=>
          string(9) "Microsoft"
        }
      }
      ["type"]=>
      string(6) "manual"
    }
  }
}
```

Your json should look like this:

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "id": "2",
        "tags": {
            "name": "Microsoft"
        },
        "type": "manual"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "tags": {
            "name": "Snow Leopard"
        },
        "type": "faq"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "tags": {
            "name": "Microsoft"
        },
        "type": "manual"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "tags": {
            "name": "Microsoft"
        },
        "type": "manual"
    }
]
}
```

And now:

```
  $array = json_decode($json);
  var_dump($array);
```

returns:

```
array(1) {
  ["items"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["tags"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(9) "Microsoft"
      }
      ["type"]=>
      string(6) "manual"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["tags"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(12) "Snow Leopard"
      }
      ["type"]=>
      string(3) "faq"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["tags"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(9) "Microsoft"
      }
      ["type"]=>
      string(6) "manual"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["tags"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(9) "Microsoft"
      }
      ["type"]=>
      string(6) "manual"
    }
  }
}
```

And array_unique works.

Comment: array_unique helps remove duplicating array but it also adds serial number! how to remove serial number from each entry?

Answer (score 0):

```
$login_data1['items'] =array_values(array_unique($login_data1['items'] ,SORT_REGULAR));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it helped me getting perfect result :)